# why is the button image is being compressed?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

Why is the image being messed up? I have a set heigh of 130 and set width of 130, and when I use the preview mode it looks fine, but for some reason the image is being compressed into a small space, and the size too. I have clipped to subviews, but it is still messed up. Why? How do I fix this?

[Image of how the constraints look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qryjs.png)

[Image of how the button image looks like on the phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7aiy.png)

```
userpic.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
```

Comment: Add a constraint to maintain fixed aspect ratio

Comment: What happens when you click on the warning and update canvas to match expectations?

Comment: @LeoDabus I added a fixed aspect ratio, but I still get the same result

Comment: @beyowulf what should I click on?

Comment: Yellow circle with arrow in it next to sign up scene in the first image you supplied. Click on all of the yellow warning signs in next pane and say update views.

Comment: Pl. give a proper constraint and remove warnings and errors and it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

***As i understand your issue, just trying to fix it...***

> ForAllObject.contentMode = Scale To Fill

[image]

*I think, It'll helps...*